# Why don't these multiline regular expressions using a positive lookbehind work?

Tags: regular-expression

**EDIT**: Don't waste time reading this question unless you're interested in a good example of why you should always check the `:help` first: a severe case of PEBKAC.

Consider the text:

```
foo
.
.
barbaz
```

Enter the following search:

```
/\(foo\_.\{-}bar\)baz
 \(             \)     # a group, containing
   foo                 #   'foo', followed by
         \{-}          #   as few as possible instances of
      \_.              #   anything, including newlines, followed by
             bar       #   'bar'
                  baz  # followed by 'baz'
```

It matches!

Now let's insert a positive lookbehind, so we only match the `baz`:

```
/\(foo\_.\{-}bar\)\@<=baz
                  \@<=     # positive lookbehind
```

> `E486: Pattern not found: \(foo\_.\{-}bar\)\@<=baz`

What's going on?

N.B. To check I'm using the zero-width @<= correctly, I tried removing the multiline part of the regex:

```
/\(bar\)\@<=baz
```

This matches the `baz`, as expected.

Note also that I tried manually specifying both of Vim's regular expression engines, which didn't help.

Finally, note that using `\zs` in place of `\@<=` works here, but not in the context in which I actually want to use the expression.

Here's another, arguably even simpler, but even more confusing example:

```
foo
foo
barbaz
```

This matches:

```
/\(foo\nbar\)baz
```

*This* matches:

```
/\(foo\nbar\)\@<=baz
```

This doesn't match:

```
/\(foo\nfoo\nbar\)\@<=baz
```

Am I doing something wrong, is this a documented limitation of Vim's regular expressions, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why spend 2 minutes reading `:help /\@<=` when you could spend 20 writing an exhaustive question for vi.se?

> Theoretically these matches could start anywhere before this position.
> But to limit the time needed, ***only the line where what follows matches
> is searched, and one line before that (if there is one)***.  This should
> be sufficient to match most things and not be too slow.

(emphasis mine)

Probably I should try actually *reading* the documentation before asking if something is documented.

As always, *je suis le idiot*. `:endless-facepalm-emoji:`

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself. ;)

Comment: @BLayer It's mostly for effect :) (...mostly). If I was *really* upset with myself I'd have left it deleted instead of undeleting it and self-answering.

Comment: I figured...but even so you were pretty rough on yourself so I had to say something . :D

Comment: @BLayer It's appreciated, either way!

Comment: My pleasure. Good find +1, by the way (even if it's right there in help). I tried matching the same thing with PCRE equivalent and it worked so I thought, too, that you might have found a bug. I didn't know...or, more likely, I forgot after reading it a long time ago...that that restriction was in place.